# Static libraries or anything else

Tags: iphone, xcode, static

I am trying to hide my source codes in iphone projects. however I didnt understand the static library concept. Most of the tutorials about static library points out that including the whole .xcodeproj . can anybody point out a direction to me please.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by hide? Who are you hiding them from? The User? Other developers?

Comment: A static library is a common way for developers to distribute or sell routines, classes, or even 99.99% of a complete app, minus, say, the artwork, to another developer, completely separate from the rights to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2009/10/13/how-to-make-an-iphone-static-library-part-1/). It's quite informative, and should get you most, if not all, of the way.